I'm trying to configure laptop fan controls on Dell G16
I’m trying to configure the laptop fan controls, but I tried a bunch of options and came to the conclusion that using i8k is already outdated with the advent of the new Kernel, and I still can’t configure pwmconfig. I'm completely confused and don’t know what else I can write useful, so I’ll try to provide data
etc/modules/
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.


# Generated by sensors-detect on Fri Apr 19 13:55:40 2024
# Chip drivers
coretemp
dell-smm-hwmon

sudo pwmconfig
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

sudo modprobe pwm-capable
modprobe: FATAL: Module pwm-capable not found in directory /lib/modules/6.5.0-28-generic

sensors
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  

nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +46.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +82.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +46.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +50.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

dell_ddv-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
CPU Fan:        0 RPM
Video Fan:      0 RPM
CPU:          +65.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
Unknown:      +59.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
Unknown:      +31.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
Video:        +56.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
SODIMM:       +56.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
SODIMM 2:     +57.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
Charger:      +54.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +67.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 8:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 12:       +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 16:       +54.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 20:       +54.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 24:       +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 28:       +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 32:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 33:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 34:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 35:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 36:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 37:       +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 38:       +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 39:       +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 40:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 41:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 42:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 43:       +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 44:       +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 45:       +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 46:       +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 47:       +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.75 V  
curr1:       1000.00 uA 

if the fans turn on automatically, this can be seen in the displayed data.
If anyone can help I would be very grateful

pwmconfig is meant for pwm fans, which laptops usually don't have.
